# How to issue "top" command from a java app?

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to use the "top" command from a standalone java app. I basically want to run this:

```
top -p myProcessId -n 1 -b
```

my java psuedocode:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -p myProcessId -n 1 -b");

// read both:
process.getInputStream();
process.getErrorStream()
```

and the output I get is:

```
top: failed tty get
```

I'm not sure what that output means - any ideas how to use "top" correctly here? I'm on ubuntu fwiw.

Thanks

----- Update -------------

OK I was able to do this instead with:

```
ps -Ao pid,rsz,cmd
```

and then I read through each output line for the process I'm interested in, I can read the res mem value from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` doesn't use the ordinary standard output stream; it manipulates the terminal device directly. This means that you can't just read in its output like you can from most command-line programs. There are a few other programs that might do what you need (`ps` is a likely candidate), or you might be able to read the relevant information from `/proc`.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm trying to get at the "RES" (resident memory?) column from top. I don't see that column using ps, I'm looking through different linux commands but not finding something like that.

Comment: Looks like you want the `rss` field: `ps -o pid,rss`.

Comment: What if I have to get CPU utilisation. 100 - idle %? I tried doing top -n 1 | Cpu >> top-output.log. Output gets stored normally when this command is run in terminal, however, from java exec Methodist is not.